# How to play a video clip from python?

Tags: python, animation, video

I started making this game a while back and I'm nearly done. All I want to do now is to make a video animation right at the start of the game. So when you click on the game icon you go directly to a video animation then to the main game screen. It will show all the people that made it and developed it. I have finished making the video animation but how do I load it to the very start of the game? I just wanted to this because I want the game to look professional. Do you use the os system command? I'm using Windows 7, Python 3.1, Pygame 3.1 and I made the video clip in windows live movie maker.

Comment: Have you tried using [`pygame.movie`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a whole module dedicated for something like this and it's part of Pygame. [pygame.movie](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html)

Comment: Note : this module is limited to MPEG1 file format.